# How do I install CKEditor with Django-WYSIWYG

Tags: django, installation, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I am trying to install the CKEditor for use with Django-WYSIWYG. This is proving to be oddly difficult.

As mentioned on the site for Django-WYSIWYG, it is possible to "install" CKEditor by dropping the distribution file in the MEDIA_URL folder on one's system.

In addition, you've got to set a variable in settings, which determines Django-WYSIWYG's "flavor."

I've done both of these things. I get no errors, but the thing still wants to use YUI. I'm really dissatisfied with YUI and would much prefer CKEditor, but for some reason it won't install.

If I am missing a step, or if you have done this somehow, please let me know!

Sorry for what is probably an obvious question.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor u can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. It is likely that you are not setting the URL correctly in your settings file. For Django 1.3, the ckeditor files are placed in static.